# Set Linux Proxy Without Restarting System

Tags: linux, proxy, environment

I tried to change my proxy in my machine since in office they use proxy and I’m not using proxy at home. So everyday I come to the office and setup the proxy using [this nice](https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan) tools. Though it is good but it requires restart in order to get all proxies applied.

Basically I know that the way to set proxy in Linux is modifying **/etc/environment** and add **http_proxy** values (or **https_proxy** for ssl), and also add **no_proxy** if you want to bypass some host/IP’s. The **ProxyMan** tool which I’ve mentioned before is basically do the same thing, but in interactive way. But still, it requires restarts to apply it all.

What I want to ask is, can we apply changes of proxy settings without restarting the machine?

Thanks…

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

The only time `/etc/environment` file is read is on login, when the PAM stack is activated. 
In deeper, its `pam_env.so`, which reads the file.

Edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` (e.g., `sudo vim /etc/pam.d/sudo`) and change `auth` to `session` at the start of the following line:

```
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
```

So it should become:

```
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
```

Comment: By using this, then it will be applied without restarting, right? I will try this later. Anyway thanks for your feedback.

Comment: After I checked my file `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file, I found that it's already set up to session. But still it doesn't affect my proxy settings.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a graphical environment, you can use a tool I have developed recently; it is hosted at https://github.com/okelet/proxychanger.